# CakePhp: Dropdowns repeating options

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm using CakePHP 2.1.1, and upgraded to 2.2.0 and the issue exists in both. I am using the FormHelper to generate a Select dropdown with the options defined in an array. When it generates the options, it repeats some of them. Which ones and how many repeat changes depending on which record I am editing.

Using the following code in my view:

```
debug($advisors);
echo $this->Form->input('advisor',array('options'=>$advisors));
```

I see:

```
/app/View/Students/edit.ctp (line 38)

array(
    'K-1' => 'K-1',
    'K-2' => 'K-2',
    '2-3' => '2-3',
    '3-5n' => '3-5n',
    '3-5s' => '3-5s',
    '4-5' => '4-5',
    '6-8' => '6-8'
)
```

and then a dropdown with the following options:

```
<option selected="selected" value="K-1">K-1</option>
<option value="K-2">K-2</option>
<option value="2-3">2-3</option>
<option value="3-5n">3-5n</option>
<option value="3-5s">3-5s</option>
<option value="4-5">4-5</option>
<option value="6-8">6-8</option>
<option value="K-1">K-1</option>
<option value="K-2">K-2</option>
<option value="2-3">2-3</option>
```

What else should I be checking?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, never mind. It was a javascript function I wrote a while back that was messing with the generated options.